# Customizar ProgressBar Android

Tags: android, progress-bar

Gostaria de desenvolver uma `ProgressBar` customizada para utilizar em minha aplicação, mas estou com dúvida de como fazer isto.

É necessário criar uma sub classe da `ProgressBar`? Dá pra fazer somente em `xml`?

Gostaria que me dessem um exemplo básico de como customizar este componente.

segue meu código, sem customização nenhuma.

Arquivo main_activity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ProgressBar 
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="250dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="100"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Classe MainActivity

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    }

    //Mais código

}
```

Comment: Que tipo de customização você quer fazer? A `ProgressBar` do Android é bem limitadazinha, então as chances de você ter que criar uma subclasse e *override* a view são grandes.

Comment: A customização que quero fazer é: mudar cor fundo de quando carrega, mudar borda, tirar os cantos arredondados e tals... Caso tenha algum componente melhor, mais customizável e com a mesma finalidade, agradeço se me disser :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu não sei te explicar direito como fazer mais vou mostrar esse exemplo que eu uso:

```
<ProgressBar
        style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Light.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edittext_url"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_progressbar" />
```

Atenção para a linha `android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_progressbar"`

**custom_progressbar.xml (res\drawable)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <gradient 
                    android:startColor="#ff49a8a6"
                    android:centerColor="#ff49a8a6"
                    android:endColor="#ff49a8a6"
                    android:angle="270.0" android:centerY="1.0"  />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**Resultado:**
[image: print android studio]

Comment: Justamente o que eu precisava! Obrigado...